# Store it in phone memory - is it possible? ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Is it possible to download an image from my app and store it in iphone memory? I have various size of images (url) available in my app. How to download from my app and store it in gallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will save an image to the gallery

```
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(yourImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo
{
    if (error != NULL)
    {
        // handle error
    }
    else 
    {
        // handle ok status
    }
}
```

More information - developer documentation page - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

How to download and store to gallery all in one:

```
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_image_address.com"]]], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: Hi ... Thank u very much Danielbeard.

Answer (score 1):

try with this tutorial. it shows how to download image and store into local memory http://sugartin.info/2012/01/10/permanently-download-image-and-fetch-locally-images/

Comment: Hi.. Thanks.. but i dont want to store it in app memory. I want to store the image in "photos" in iphone common feature. is it possible to do this?